# How to format heading of chapters with out affecting bibliography heading?

Tags: bibliographies, titlesec

I am doing my documentation in latex. But they have given specifications in ms office. as like this for inner pages.[image]
I want this format from ms office for all my chapter headings[image: 14 font size and bold]

After adding this code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\fillast} 
{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\space\thechapter : #1 }}{1ex 
minus .1ex}{\bfseries\uppercase}
```

It has became like this
[image]

**note: Document class is report. and i need font size of chapter heading as 14 pt. I need chapter number and chapter name in different lines**

Also my bibliography heading is missed. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To get help with any question you need to post the smallest possible piece of compliable code that demonstrates and reproduces your problem. Without knowing details like your document class this question is impossible to answer. Please don't post a huge amount of code: the code should be as small as possible.  


For your bibliography problem, we again need more details about what you are doing but chances are you can find the solution with a quick search on TeX.SX because questions about bibliographies appear frequently.

Comment: Yeah I made some changes. And added some new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out i figured out the solution with following code.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter \normalfont\fontsize{14}{14}\bfseries}
{\MakeUppercase\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5mm} 
{\MakeUppercase{\fontsize{14}{14} #1}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0 mm}{10 mm}{10 mm}
```

It look like this now. Also the references heading started to appear.
[image]